# Strange sound produced by Android Emulator when turned on in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I've just update my Android Studio together with the Android Emulator to the newest version. After I click "run" in my project and selected my emulator,  it boots up like normal. However, when the app pops up, I can hear some strange noise produced. I've made sure that I didn't set the app to play any sound. [Link to the strange noise](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CMMAN3v0BH0ehigIa84Qd4OWROy_HtEs)

Android Emulator: Galaxy Nexus API 27
Android Studio Version: 3.0.1

Comment: I've stopped using Android Emulator a long time ago, it always had issues. Try Genymotion, or even bluestacks

Comment: Anyone has a good solution for that? Will be thankful

Comment: I have given up on Android emulators a long time ago, but I can suggest you try these emulators: [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) and [bluestacks](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us). Genymotion will give you a lot of devices to choose from.

Comment: That's very strange. I've tried other projects but they doesn't produce the noise

Comment: @Kemo you're right. The emulator had got many issues

Comment: Hope one of these two emulators will help you :)

Comment: I tried a project, not sure if it is related to added vibration. the app emit beep beep or tok tok tok tok sound.. even I closed the emulator, it keep emitting the sound. I need to close the Android Studio. @Banana But it is not convenient when debugging to use other emulator (need generate apk??) while codes are written in Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sound was actually the notification sound of the emulator. Since my app is in landscape mode, it needed me to configure the keyboard in landscape mode. So the notification came out.

Answer (score 24):

### Turn off `Touch Sounds` on the Android device/emulator.

You can find it under `Settings` -> `Sound & notification` -> `Other sounds` -> `Touch sounds`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Android 10/11/12 emulators, this odd "sparkle" sound happens when rotating the device to landscape or portrait. Here's how to turn it off:

[image: Google Android emulator screenshots - status bar notification for "Configure Physical Keyboard"]

1. Launch your Android 10 or 11 emulator (API 29 or 30)
2. Drag and pull down the notification bar at the top <kbd>(screenshot A)</kbd>
3. You should see a **"Configure physical keyboard"** notification from the status bar. Drag it to the right slowly and by a small amount, to reveal the settings cog icon ️️⚙️ <kbd>(screenshot B)</kbd>
4. Press the Settings cog icon ⚙️ to reveal the expanded options <kbd>(screenshot C)</kbd>
5. Click on **"Silent - No sound or vibration"**, then click **"Apply/Done"**
6. Optional: If a "Configure physical keyboard" notification still appears, swipe it to the right, to remove it.

**Another way - Android 10/11**

1. On the Home screen, swipe up to reveal all the apps
2. Settings ➔ Apps & Notifications ➔ Notifications ➔ Android System ➔ Physical Keyboard (and/or Virtual Keyboard) ➔ Switch it off or click it and set it to Silent.

**Another way - Android 12 (API 31)**

1. On the Home screen, swipe up to reveal all the apps
2. Settings ➔ Notifications ➔ App Settings ➔ Click the '3 dots' menu at the top ➔ Show System (to reveal system apps in the list) ➔ Android System ➔ Physical Keyboard (and/or Virtual Keyboard) ➔ Switch it off or click it and set it to Silent.

[image: Android 11 Settings app - Notifications]

Now there are no more annoying noises when changing the emulator's orientation.

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to multiple reasons:
One of the reason is

1. If you turn your laptop Bluetooth ON. If that is the case, turn Bluetooth off and restart the emulator.